# Why does `/usr/bin/time` report the wrong exit status with format `%x` in case of SIGABRT?

Tags: command-line, signal, coreutils

I'm using `/usr/bin/time` to report information about a set of benchmarks I'm running. The interesting data points are runtime, memory usage and the exit status. This works fine except when the application fails with an uncaught exception, in which case `/usr/bin/time` reports a `0` exit code instead of the actual `134`.

Let me illustrate the problem with a toy example for the app:

```
#include <stdexcept>

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    throw std::runtime_error("test"); // 1
    //return 134;                     // 2
}
```

and the following call:
`/usr/bin/time -f "%x" ./app ; echo $?`.

Throwing the error (line 1 not commented) results in the following output:

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::runtime_error'
  what():  test
Command terminated by signal 6
0
134
```

whereas actually returning the exit status (line 2 not commented) works:

```
Command exited with non-zero status 134
134
134
```

`/usr/bin/time --version` reports an `UNKNOWN` version, but I see the same behavior on Ubuntu 20.04 and 22.04.
I suspect it has something to do with the SIGABRT (signal 6), but I cannot find a fix or an explanation for the behavior.

How can I get `/usr/bin/time` to report the correct exit status in cases of uncaught exceptions?

Comment: Note that "134" might be a fiction made up by your shell. Bash, at least, when it sees that a child process was killed by a signal, sets the exit status to 128+<signal number>, but that's just Bash trying to be helpful.

Comment: That's a good point. After reading a bit more into the topic of signals, I think I misunderstood how SIGABRT works. Do you think I makes sense to ask this question in Unix & Linux?

Comment: I think you find most of the information you need in https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/99112/70524. You can try something like `/usr/bin/time -f "%x" bash -c './app; exit $?'` instead to get the fake exit status reported by the shell, but your results for other statistics maybe slightly off due to the intervening shell.

Comment: That really did help, both with understanding better how signals work and how to fix my issue. Do you want to post this as an answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The exit status of 134 that you see here is the value reported by the shell, probably bash in this case, on behalf of the killed process to indicate that it was killed by a signal. The exact behaviour of this reporting varies between shells, so you'd see different values instead of 134 for the same situation with, say, ksh. The entire situation is explained thoroughly in the answers to [this Unix & Linux post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/99112/70524).

Worse yet, as this is a feature of the shell, other programs aren't expected to do the same. The `time` command instead prints a message notifying about the signal-induced termination (`Command terminated by signal 6`), but reports 0.

You can instead call the shell with `time`, and use it to report the exit status you want. This might influence other metrics that you might care about for benchmarking, but should work:

```
/usr/bin/time -f "%x" bash -c './app; exit $'
```

On Ubuntu, `/bin/sh` is `dash`, but it should have the same behaviour as bash in this respect according to the linked U&L post. As `dash` is considerably more lightweight than bash, you could use `sh -c` instead of `bash -c` here and have less of an impact on metrics.